# What does a principal polynomial ideal consist of?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

I understand the definition of an ideal, and in particular, that of a principal ideal. For example, consider the principle ideal $(2)$ of $\mathbb{Z}$. This is the set of all multiples of the integer $2$ - i.e. the even numbers. I understand this from the definition and from an intuitive point of view.

But when considering principal ideals of polynomial rings, I lose this intuition entirely. For example, consider the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$ and the principal ideal $(x^4+x^2+x+1)$ of it. What does this consist of? In a sense, it must be multiples of $x^4+x^2+x+1$. Is this correct?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Why do you doubt it?

Comment: I'm really just questioning what we're multiplying $x^4+x^2+x+1$ by exactly... is it just by every other possible polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$?

Comment: What definition of "ideal" are you using?

Comment: An ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is a subset that satisfies 3 properties: 1) $0 \in I$; 2) $u, v \in I \implies u+v \in I$; and 3) If $x \in R, u \in I$, then $xu \in I$.

Comment: So by the 3rd closure condition $\ u\in I \Rightarrow uR \subseteq I.\,$ Further it is easy to check that $\, uR\,$ satisfies the 1st two conditions, so $uR$ is an ideal - clearly the smallest ideal of $R$ containing $u.\,$

Comment: Intuitively the ideal generated by $\,m\,$ is the set of all elements that are forced by ring axioms to be zero if we assume that $m$ is zero. Just like for integers this defines a congruence relation whose kernel (all elts $\equiv 0)$ has the structure of an ideal. This will become clearer when you study quotient rings - generalizations of $\,\Bbb Z_m = \Bbb Z/m  = $ integers mod $m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In a sense, it must be multiples of $x^4+x^2+x+1$. Is this correct?

Yes, in this context, it is right. I think the sense you're thinking of is called "set equality."

In any commutative ring $R$ with identity, for any $x\in R$, $(x)=xR$.

It's very easy to see. Firstly, $xR$ is an ideal containing $1\cdot x =x$, and any ideal containing $x$ must contain $xr$ for all $r\in R$, so $xR$ is the smallest ideal containing $x$.